# How to trigger an function from multiple starting points?

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```
$(function() {
    $('#toggle-event').change(function() {
        if($(this).prop('checked') == true){
            $('.textfield, .editable_textfield').toggleClass('textfield editable_textfield');
            $('.textfield, .editable_textfield').editable('option', 'disabled', false);

            $('.editable_selectfield_1').editable({
                source: [
                      {value: 'ja', text: 'Ja'},
                      {value: 'nee', text: 'Nee'},
                   ],
                });
            $('.editable_selectfield_1').editable('option', 'disabled', false);
        }
        else
        {
            $('.textfield, .editable_textfield').editable('option', 'disabled', true);
            $('.editable_selectfield_1').editable('option', 'disabled', true);
        }
    });
})
```

This function can be triggerd by:

```
<input id="toggle-event" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="mini" data-on="<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>" data-off="<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>" data-onstyle="danger">
```

But now I want this button to be shown an multiple places on the same page. The ID needs to be uniqye to be able run the script, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a class name as your selector instead of an ID. Use the same class name on the toggle items.

```
<input class="toggle" id="toggle-event" type="checkbox".... >

 $('.toggle').change(function() { ....
```